# Hide URL of PHP page

Tags: php, url

I want to hide the URL of my PHP page; that is, I don't want to write `/register.php` directly in the href tag, I want to write `/register/` and have it open the `register.php` page directly. I want to do that for all the webpages.

Comment: You can probably use URL rewriting; what webserver are you using?

Comment: ok...I am using domain services from justhost. I think they are providing apache webserver.

Answer (score 3):

In .htaccess try this :

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html); it's a Apache module that will help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

umm quick fix is to make a directory called register and save it as the index.php then make sure all your forms have `action="/register/"` (assuming register is a root folder of domain)

Comment: It sounds like he has a number of pages; he just wants `/foo/` to redirect to `/foo.php` for any `foo`

Comment: Hello,

I have written code for this...

<p class="text13"><a rel="nofollow" href="/register/">Register</a></p> 

This is not working...saying page not found. I have created a folder called register and inside the folder i have index.php file. 

Also tell me if I want to open another page inside the same folder how can i do without writting the extension.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Check the website http://phpclasses.byting.at/browse/ they are opening a page with the help of the folder name....

Comment: if you want to use more than one script your going to want to use the .htaccess method described above

Answer (score 0):

Rest easy .. I am new to web development also and I had trouble making this solution work. The detail that is not obvious is that in the php code links, you should remove the extension. For example :

`<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
should read 
<li><a href="index">Home</a></li>`

Then the extension goes away.