# I need to hide .php file name in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to hide the file name with the extinction of .php.I tried to write .htaccess file to restrict my URL.but it is not hiding. any one can help me step by step how to hide the URL.
bellow I mentioned actual URL.and expected URL.

Actual URL   :  varthakindia.com/inners.php?cid1=Hotels

Expected URL:  varthakindia.com/Hotels/

Comment: Use mod_rewrite with `htaccess`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13896810/hide-url-directory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645411/url-hiding-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007284/hide-url-of-php-page

Answer (score 3):

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Hotels$ inners.php?cid1=Hotels [L,NS]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use mod_rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^Hotels/?$ inners.php?cid1=Hotels [L, NS]
```

Comment: I just don't understand this, why answer the same thing ???????

Comment: @php_nub_qq — It isn't the same, it is just very similar … and answered within the same minute. It is possible for two people to independently write near identical code, especially when it is so trivial.

Comment: Oh both the answers are same Great

Comment: And yet the late one gets the rep, how awesome!

Comment: Don't be angry, @php_nub_qq, you got one, too. Also, as I think you must undertstand that you're not alone here trying to answer in the same time.

Comment: You get to know when you are writing an answer that an answer is posted you must have checked it instead of writing unnecessary answers right? I am not blaming you for this but you should have

Comment: @NetStarter there were no answer when I started :)

Comment: Yes but when you it shows a minute difference between both the answers?

Comment: gr8 it is showing the same time now both 9 mins ago.We must have a duplicate answer option on SO